# Hibernate disabling 2nd level cache

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, second-level-cache

In hibernate SQL .. I did the following in the hibernate config xml file :

```
 <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
     org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
  </property>

      <property name = "org.hibernate.cacheable">false</property>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
```

In the code I did the following:

```
public static List<Object> selectFromStudents(String queryName, Object[]                queryParameters) {
    Session  session = null;
    List<Object> queryList = null;
    try{
        session = mySessionFactory.openSession();
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery(queryName);
        query.setCacheable(false);

        if (queryParameters != null) { 
            // set the query parameters 
            for (int i = 0; i < queryParameters.length; i++) {
                query.setParameter(i, queryParameters[i]);
            }
        }
        // execute the query
        queryList = (List<Object>) query.list();
    } catch(HibernateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if(session != null){
            session.clear();
            session.close();    
        }
        if(queryList != null){
            return queryList;
        }
        else{
            // no data returned
            return new ArrayList<Object>();  
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is when I excute the same query twice it gives the same result .. which means that in the second time it gets the cached result not from database

I want it to always access database. What is the solution.

Comment: I have doubts your assumption is correct. Did you check the second level cache statistics?

Comment: yes it shows in the console that it is disabled

Comment: Right, so then 2LC is not the reason why the query returns twice the same result then :). I still don't understand what your question is TBH. You're executing the same query multiple times, and I don't see any updates to the entities, so everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: in fact it changes in the database .. but in the hibernate i'm getting the same result (no change)

Comment: How's the database being updated? Via Hibernate too? And are these updates coming from the same node/machine? Or from a different one?